# Livewire Datepicker Close after Render on Laravel 8

Tags: datepicker, laravel-8, render, laravel-livewire

Suppose I change the start date and click on End Date before render the start date. Then datepicker of End date will be close because of rendering of start date value. If you have any solution or any datepicker suggestion, please help me.

**Blade File**

```
<div class="col">
    <label for="">Start Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" wire:model.lazy='start_date'
        class="form-control @error('start_date') is-invalid @enderror">
    @error('start_date')
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label for="">End Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" wire:model.lazy='end_date'
        class="form-control @error('end_date') is-invalid @enderror">
    @error('end_date')
        <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
    @enderror
</div>
```

**My Script Code for Datepicker**

```
<script>
    $('input[name=start_date]').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        disabledDates: false,
        useCurrent: false,
        showClear: true,
        showClose: true,
        showTodayButton: true,

    });
    $('input[name=start_date]').on("dp.change", function(e) {
        @this.set('start_date', e.target.value);
    });

    $('input[name=end_date]').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        disabledDates: false,
        useCurrent: false,
        showClear: true,
        showClose: true,
        showTodayButton: true,
    });
    $('input[name=end_date]').on("dp.change", function(e) {
        @this.set('end_date', e.target.value);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstand you question why you use "wire:model.lazy" ? "wire:model" remove **.lazy** might be fixed your problem?